# iptables port forwarding to another webserver port

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables, port-forwarding

Is it possible to forward a port to a port belonging to another webserver?

I have an ec2 instance which is capable to connect to a mysql db living on another machine not belonging to the same network.
ie
aws-machine:XXXX => internet-website:YYYY

I tried with port forwarding with the following config but it does not work.

```
sudo ufw allow from any to any port XXXX proto tcp
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport XXXX-j DNAT --to-destination internet-website:YYYY
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport XXXX -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport XXXX -j MASQUERADE
```

The idea is to create a tunnel to connect to the db without being logged on the machine or using an ssh tunnel.
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the traffic through the FORWARD chain, not the INPUT chain.

INPUT is traffic destined to the local machine; FORWARD is traffic passing thru the local machine.

Because the `filter` table (where INPUT and FORWARD chains live) is processed after the `nat` table (where PREROUTING is), the `filter` table is processing the packet *after* you've altered it to DNAT to the remote host, therefore the packet is sent through the FORWARD chain, not the INPUT chain.